# set id value in AUTO_INCREMENT field with laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have tried to set value id of new row in laravel 5 , by `Point::create($value)` and `new Point($value)` the `$value` contains a id value and this id doesn't exist in mysql db.
and every time I try the new row has got a auto id not that in `$value`

Comment: show us `dd($value)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `id` in your `fillable` array in `Point` model class.

```
protected $fillable = [
    'id'
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a custom primary key with:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'custom_key';
```

If you don't have PK, do this:

```
protected $primaryKey = null;
public $incrementing = false;
```

Also, remove it from `fillable()` array. In this case, `id` will be ignored.

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#defining-models):

> Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named `id`. You may define a protected `$primaryKey` property to override this convention.
>
> In addition, Eloquent assumes that the primary key is an incrementing integer value, which means that by default the primary key will be cast to an `int` automatically. If you wish to use a non-incrementing or a non-numeric primary key you must set the `public $incrementing property` on your model to `false`. If your primary key is not an integer, you should set the protected `$keyType` property on your model to string.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make `id` fillable, than you can use next instead of `Point::create($value)`:

```php
$point = Point::make($value);
$point->id = $value['id'];
$point->save();
```

Also you can `Point::unguard()` to temporarily disregard the fillable status of fields and make `id` temporary fillable.